# Android Droid 1 only partially recognizes SD

Tags: sd-card, motorola-droid

My Motorola Droid began experiencing a weird quirk where when booted it recognizes the SD card, but only once. After that some applications complain that there is no SD card inserted and persist until rebooting again.

For example, I can take a picture, but any attempt to take another picture results in a warning that an SD card must be inserted.

Oddly, music and apps which were installed on the SD card work fine, and I can browse it with a file browser. What causes some apps to not recognize it and others to work just fine?

It's probably worth noting that I'm using a Liquid Smooth ROM with Launcher Pro; though I hadn't had any problems of that type until today.

Comment: Could the partially be reading but not writing? I have seen instances where a Sd card was locked for any further writes until it was fixed of its corruptions. Some devices would attempt to do some sort of corruption fix and store deemed to be broken stuff in special folders.  If i ever got in that situation, with an Externaly available card, I would deal with it in a card reader in the big PC.  Copy all usable off, reformat on the pc OR reformat in the device so it puts on its own desired file system, then copy back from the PC.

Comment: The corruption that was occuring for me was a GPS tracking type program that did constant writes, in what might be a poor writing method. when stopped also with bad stopping methods the write was not properly closed, and corruption again existed. IF there was corruptions occuring and getting locked out, getting to the bottom of why , can be more important than getting it working once again.  These EXT file systems can have ways of dealing with corruption that are "better" or worse depending on what the problem is, so using the device format for the file system, the device expects that.

Comment: is it ok to format? I was afraid of doing so in the past in case the ROM or CWM had data there

Comment: I do not know about special things being there from those 2 items. a removable disk shouldnt have system critical on it, but i just do not know.